# setup.py register server returns code 308

Tags: python, setuptools, pypi

I've been trying to get a package to be indexed into pypi, but I ran into a problem. Whenever I try to register the package using

```
setup.py register
```

the command asks for user and password(looking good so far) but then prints this line

```
Registering create_api_django to https://pypi.python.org/pypi
Server response (308): Redirect to Primary Domain
```

I cannot for the life of me figure how to change the repository it is trying to access (since it should be https://pypi.org/)

Can anyone help me?

Thank you.

Comment: `register`/`upload` commands were removed from `setuptools`. Use `twine`.